# Compiling and linking a 32 bit application on Debian 64 bit

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, debian, 32-bit

I am currently trying to compile and link a 32 bit application on my Debian 64 bit, but it fails at link time.

The command I'm using (in my Makefile) to compile is:

```
gcc -Os -m32 -Wall -g -c $< -o $@
```

This seems to work.

Then I link with the following command:

```
gcc -m32 -lcurses $^ -o $@
```

This fails and gives the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../libcurses.so when searching for -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../libcurses.a when searching for -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurses.so when searching for -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurses.a when searching for -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I've tried so far (usual solutions that I found elsewhere on the web) is:

- installing `gcc-multilib`
- installing `lib32ncurses5` and `lib32ncurses6dev`
- adding the option `-L/usr/lib32` to the link command

Sadly, none of these has worked so far.
I am running out of ideas. My last resort would be using a 32 bit system, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Your link command is incorrect: the order of libraries on the link line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html). The command should be: `gcc -m32 $^ -o $@ -lcurses`
2. Since you want to link against *ncurses*, make the last argument `-lncurses`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works!

The first point did not change anything in my case, but thanks for the information, I did not know about that.

The second point solved my issue, amazingly enough. How did you know I wanted to link against ncurses and not curses? I myself didn't know that... (I'm not really sure of the difference between the two, except ncurses is supposedly newer...?)

Comment: "How did you know I wanted to link against ncurses and not curses?" You've installed `lib32ncurses6dev` package ;-)

Comment: Indeed, but that's mainly because it's the only package that seemed close to what I was looking for. And I have both curses and ncurses in 32 and 64 bits, so I don't really see why it works in 64 bits with curses and ncurses, but only with ncurses in 32 bits. Anyway, it works as I need it! Thanks ;)

Comment: When you have this error, the lib named in error, did they come too SOON or too LATE in the link order?

Answer (score 0):

The message shows gcc didn't find the 32bit of ncurse library.

A quick solution: looking on my machine (ubuntu 11.10) , I think should be

```
gcc -m32 -lncurses $^ -o $@ -v
```

Where the library is actually at /lib32/libncurses.so.5.9.

Generally, try if you encounter a problem.

```
gcc -m32 -lcurses $^ -o $@ -v
```

It'll print out a lot of stuff.

Look for parameters looks like -L, and try to find the library file (libfoo.so or libfoo.a) in the directory .

Comment: But the `-lncurses` should be after `$^`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the `lib32ncurses5-dev` package, or something similar, providing the 32 bits variant development package for ncurses.