# Compiling C++ with g++ -m32 option

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I am trying to compile as this :

`-bash-4.1$ g++ -static -m32 Hello.cpp`

and getting errors like this:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.2.1/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.2.1/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.2.1/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried this as well **but still get the exact same error above**:

`g++ -static -m32 -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.2.1/32 Hello.cpp`

I have tried in both orders - nothing helps.

Why is it still looking at the wrong directory?
Is using `-m32` option override `-L` option?
I could not find much documentation on `-m32` option.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and linking a 32 bit application on Debian 64 bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197617/compiling-and-linking-a-32-bit-application-on-debian-64-bit)

Comment: You may add `-v` or/and `-###` options to the compile line to check the verbose output. And check if your path exists in this output, Alson -m32 option does not override -L. `-m32` is for compiling 32bit binaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why is it still looking at the wrong directory?
  Compiler always looking in predefined directories first. `-L` options adds your path to these list of directories, so because of it compiler is *stil looking* at the wrong directory. For more detailed output try to compiler your program with detailed output `-###` or `-v` options.
- Is using -m32 option override -L option?
  The answer is no - `-m32` options is option to generate 32bit code, for example: 
  You may generate 32bit code that will work on 32bit machine, on your 64bit machine. Also you may run this code on your 64bit machine - it will work well.
- I could not find much documentation on -m32 option.
  Here is the link to the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options)
  And here is doc about [directory searching options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Also to say to compiler where to find libraries, you may set
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your env
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB`
Do not override env vars - cause it may cause more problems if you are not absolutely sure in what you are doing.

Comment: This issue was also with the way the server was setup. I had to add custom path changes as instructed by the server admin.